# spark-submit gives out NullPointerException

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to create a simple python script. When I write the code in pyspark shell, it works ok. But when I try to use spark-submit with the following:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

This is the error message I got. I am using Anaconda python, is there any other setup I need to do? Thanks
[image: spark-submit error message]

Answer (score 0):

You should specify master address, something like:

```
SparkConf().setMaster("local[4]")
```

Also, when you use spark-submit script, make sure your **Spark cluster is up and running**, also make sure the **firewall is not blocking** your cluster node communication since communication happens at port at something like 27231.

Give it a try, good luck.

Comment: When I run it on cluster it is working, but when I am trying on my stand-alone, it just won't let me, is there any config I miss on my stand-alone?

Comment: did you try to add "setMaster" to conf? since when you submit to cluster, the master node is already defined, but your stand-alone mode, I'm not sure if you are using in-memory or spin different threads as master and worker. also maybe check you firewall, I had the problem too and it turned out to be firewall blocking self-looping to localhost